# Get the listview selected index?

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp, win-universal-app

I am creating UWP project. In that i am using listview to display the content. Dynamically adding the content to listview and successfully done it. I have an issue when i was selecting the content **selectedIndex** value always in -1.

```
            <ListView Name="MyListView" IsItemClickEnabled="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="MyListView_SelectionChanged_1">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListViewItem Height="80" Width="290"  Tapped="ListViewItem_Tapped"   Margin="-10,0,-10,0">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-10,0,-24,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="288" >
                                    <Border Background="#E94F08" Height="75" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="288" CornerRadius="50" >
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Ellipse Height="68" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/4.jpg"/>
                                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                                            </Ellipse>
                                            <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name }" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20">
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ListViewItem>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: Just a note: You don't need to use a ListViewItem in the data template, the whole data template will be wrapped by a ListViewItem when ListView creates items.

Comment: i am also using listviewitem inside the data template. but that's not my problem  i need to get selectedindex or selected value i can't get those please help.@MehrzadChehraz

Comment: The provided code is not enough to find the problem, not for me at least.

Comment: that's my code for listview

Comment: You need to provide the code to answer this questions: How do you determine the selected index? And show the code behind the listview logic...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

## XAML

```
 <ListView x:Name="listViewName" 
           IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
           SelectionMode="Single" 
           SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged">
 </ListView>
```

## C#

```
private void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = listViewName.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is remove the `ListViewItem` from the `ItemTemplate`, because everything you put in that template is already wrapped in a `ListViewItem`. By removing this, you also remove the incorrect tapped eventhandler.

Next step is setting `IsItemClickEnabled="True"` instead of `False` to tell the `ListView` that people can actually click/tap your items. You can no handle either the `SelectionChanged` event or the `ItemClicked` event, the second having the upside that multiple clicks on the same item are also registered (if you need this).

I updated your XAML to:

```
<ListView Name="MyListView" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="MyListView_SelectionChanged_1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-10,0,-24,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="288" >
                <Border Background="#E94F08" Height="75" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="288" CornerRadius="50" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Ellipse Height="68" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/4.jpg"/>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name }" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In case you need the SelectedItem instead of the index, it's maybe easier to bind the SelectedItem property. Don't forget to use Mode=TwoWay on the binding.